# Ошибка в коде телеграмм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я пишу тг-бота на python с использованием aiogram.

При написании логики для очков здоровья я наткнулся на ошибку:

```
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'health' where it is not associated with a value
```

Вот полный код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

TOKEN = ''

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
health = int(100)
coins = 0
commands = ['hit']

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def type_start_bot(message: types.Message):
await message.reply('выбирай что будем делать?')
@dp.message_handler(commands=['hit'])
async def type_hit_bot(message:types.Message):
    await message.reply('бот избил вас так как он сильней')
    if commands == ['hit']: 
        health -= 50 <--- ОШИБКА ТУТ
        async def type_health_bot(message:types.Message):
        await message.reply(health)
@dp.message_handler(commands=['mybio'])
async def type_bio_bot(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(health)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать для устранения ошибки?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В начале функции `type_hit_bot` пропиши `global health`. Должно помочь.

Comment: если в начале функции поставить global heath то выдаст syntax error: invalid syntax

Comment: Тогда при объявлении переменных сделай глобальной.

Comment: global health | health = int(100)